# Reading two level xml in php

Tags: php, xml

I have xml file like:

```
<DATA>
    <DATAITEM>
        <id>0001</id>
        <name>Chair</name>
        <price>400</price>
    </DATAITEM>
    <DATAITEM>
        <id>0002</id>
        <name>Table</name>
        <price>1200</price>
    </DATAITEM>
</DATA>
```

and I have this php script:

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    foreach($xml_file->DATA as $xml){
        $value = htmlspecialchars($xml->DATAITEM->id);
    }
}
```

The problem is, that in the each step of the cycle while is in the variable value saved only the first item of the xml file. It's logical, because only the first item of the xml file has the path begun with DATA and the second one not. But I don't know how to save also the second item of the xml file into variable $value. I hope that you'll understand my problem.

Comment: You are overwriting the value of `$value` each time you run the loop.  Try adding a dot `.` before your equal sign to append the data or do something with your `$value` in the foreach loop if you would prefer to do that.

Comment: I need to do: Start the first step while loop, start the foreach loop, take the first item of the xml file, make the commands in the foreach loop. Take the secont item of the xml file, make the commands in the foreach loop. Start the second step while loop etc.

Comment: Where does `$xml_file` come from? What does `$row` have to do with everything else? Is this real code or some pseudo-code you've written in advance?

Comment: The foreach code iterates once for every $xml_file->DATA tag.  And there is only one of them (so you get one result).  I believe you want to iterate $xml_file->DATA->DATAITEM.

Comment: It's only example xml code. Original code is very very long...

Comment: If I do it like @James writes, the white screen is displayed and no script runs. But you wrote the main point from the problem that I need to solve.

Comment: What kind of php object is $xml_file?

Comment: @James command echo wrotes object
command print_r wrotes SimpleXMLElement Object

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a working sample similar to your code

```
$xml = "<DATA>
    <DATAITEM>
        <id>0001</id>
        <name>Chair</name>
        <price>400</price>
    </DATAITEM>
    <DATAITEM>
        <id>0002</id>
        <name>Table</name>
        <price>1200</price>
    </DATAITEM>
</DATA>";

$x = new SimpleXMLElement($xml);

foreach ($x->DATAITEM as $item) {
  $value = $item->id;
}
```

As Quixrick pointed out in the comments, the $value variable will be overwritten each time the loop iterates.  You could create an array and store the id values as elements in that array:

```
$value = array();
foreach ($x->DATAITEM as $item) {
  $value[] = $item->id;
}
// do something with $value, an array containing all of the id values
```

Comment: Have I to copy the content of xml file in variable $xml or can I use simplexml_load_file function?

Comment: Yes you can use the load_file function, I just did it like this to provide a working example.